# Reacts select onChange get key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

does anybody know how to retrieve the "key" value from a select when the function onChange is triggered?

```
callback(e) {
  e.target.value;
}
...
<select onChange={this.callback.bind(this)}>
    <option key={obj.id}>{obj.name}</option>
    <option key={obj.id}>{obj.name}</option>
</select>
```

I know I can get the value of obj.name with target.value but I can't find out how to retreive the key.

Comment: why would you want the key? that for React to keep track of the order, if you need obj.id, just pass in id={obj.id} and access it that way

Comment: I thought about passing the id. I'd do something like callback.bind(this, obj.id) . Problem is I generate the option tags with an array.map and I can't access directly obj.id

Comment: Also I'd like to know why people are downvoting this question, since so far none but Danny managed to find an answer and even that one isn't that trivial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the id to a data attribute, then access it from e.target. A modified version of your example:

```
callback(e) {
  for (let node of e.target.children) {
    if (node.value === e.target.value) {
      console.log(node.getAttribute('data-id');
      return;
    }
  }
}
...
<select onChange={this.callback.bind(this)}>
    <option key={obj1.id} data-id={obj1.id} value={obj1.value}>{obj1.name}</option>
    <option key={obj2.id} data-id={obj2.id} value={obj2.value}>{obj2.name}</option>
</select>
```

Edit:

Modified above example to fix issue, since e.target actually refers to the select element, not the option element. You need to find the selected option then get its data-id attribute. Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/50706/

Comment: Looks close, very close to what I'm looking for. I tested it, but it gives me "null" on the output. I saw something close but for stuff like: button onClick(). Maybe here the problem is that we are in a select.

Comment: Ah. This is because e.target refers to the select element rather than the option element. Need to search for the selected option.

Comment: It works... kinda! Fix the console log with this: console.log(node.getAttribute('data-id')); and I accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
callback(e) {
  e.target.value; // Changed value
  e.target.selectedIndex; // Index of the change value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is older than my children, but a mix of the two answers above: since you're likely generating the `<option>` elements via props, you could use the `select` element's `selectedIndex` value, then index into your props to get the object used to generate the `option` in the first place.

```
function DropDown({ current, options, onChange }) {
  return (
    <select value={current} onChange={(event) => {
      const { selectedIndex } = event.target;
      onChange(options[selectedIndex]);
    }}>
      {options.map(({ value, key }) => (<option key={key}>{value}</option>))}
    </select>
  );
}

<DropDown
  current={'ABC'}
  options={[
    { value: 'ABC', key: 'key:abc' },
    { value: 'IJK', key: 'key:ijk' },
    { value: 'XYZ', key: 'key:xyz' },
  ]}
  onChange={(obj) => {
    console.log('Changed to object', { obj });
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about reactjs, but retrieving the selected value in javascript is:

`element.options[element.selectedIndex].value`

So maybe try:

`element.options[element.selectedIndex].key`

Where element is your actual select.

Comment: Thank you, sadly a solution with target.key doesn't work. Reactjs uses a virtual DOM and has it's own way to do stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the `key` and `label` in the `onChange` event of select in React is:

```
console.log('Label ️', event.target.selectedOptions[0].label);
console.log(event.target.value);
```